# How to calculate Average value using functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thank you in advance.

I have a `table1` and `table2`

**table1**

```
id   ||  date        || name_id   ||   value   
001  || 2017-12-01   || 212       || 23.091
002  || 2017-12-02   || 212       || 20.324
003  || 2017-12-03   || 212       || 21.765
004  || 2017-12-04   || 212       || 25.890
005  || 2017-12-01   || 497       || 23.291
006  || 2017-12-02   || 497       || 20.524
007  || 2017-12-03   || 497       || 21.705
008  || 2017-12-04   || 497       || 25.810
009  || 2017-11-01   || 242       || 23.492
010  || 2017-11-02   || 242       || 20.744
011  || 2017-11-03   || 242       || 21.076
012  || 2017-11-04   || 242       || 24.100
013  || 2017-10-01   || 197       || 23.376
014  || 2017-10-02   || 197       || 20.555
015  || 2017-10-03   || 197       || 21.965
016  || 2017-10-04   || 197       || 25.120
```

**table2**

```
id   ||  startup_date  || Name  
212  || 2017-11-31     || BVUNMI
497  || 2017-11-30     || OUKNGT
242  || 2017-10-26     || TYNBFD
197  || 2017-09-28     || WDRHBG
```

**Output**

```
id   ||  startup_date  || Name      ||   Avg_value
212  || 2017-11-31     || BVUNMI    ||   22.7675
497  || 2017-11-30     || OUKNGT    ||   23.291
242  || 2017-10-26     || TYNBFD    ||   22.353
197  || 2017-09-28     || WDRHBG    ||   22.754
```

this is just a sample data. I have 1000's of records and unable to figure out how to do it.

**The logic** is I need to calculate the average value for the **first** 30 days from the startup date.
I have to take the average value of each NAME_ID and create, update into a new column in table2.

I am stuck and don't how to go further.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2017-11-31 - doesn't exist

So I changed it to 2017-11-30, that's why my result slightly different than yours. unfortunately, such a query can give bad performance on large volumes of data. I would suggest denormalizing data a bit if it's possible (add start_date into t1)

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
declare @t1 table(id int , dt date, name_id int, value decimal(15,2))
declare @t2 table(id int , startup_date date, Name nvarchar(100))
insert into @t1(id,dt,name_id,value)
values
(001,convert(date,'2017-12-01',121),212    ,23.091),
(002,convert(date,'2017-12-02',121),212    ,20.324),
(003,convert(date,'2017-12-03',121),212    ,21.765),
(004,convert(date,'2017-12-04',121),212    ,25.890),
(005,convert(date,'2017-12-01',121),497    ,23.291),
(006,convert(date,'2017-12-02',121),497    ,20.524),
(007,convert(date,'2017-12-03',121),497    ,21.705),
(008,convert(date,'2017-12-04',121),497    ,25.810),
(009,convert(date,'2017-11-01',121),242    ,23.492),
(010,convert(date,'2017-11-02',121),242    ,20.744),
(011,convert(date,'2017-11-03',121),242    ,21.076),
(012,convert(date,'2017-11-04',121),242    ,24.100),
(013,convert(date,'2017-10-01',121),197    ,23.376),
(014,convert(date,'2017-10-02',121),197    ,20.555),
(015,convert(date,'2017-10-03',121),197    ,21.965),
(016,convert(date,'2017-10-04',121),197    ,25.120)

insert into @t2(id,startup_date,Name)
VALUES 
(212,convert(date,'2017-11-30',121),'BVUNMI'),
(497,convert(date,'2017-11-30',121),'OUKNGT'),
(242,convert(date,'2017-10-26',121),'TYNBFD'),
(197,convert(date,'2017-09-28',121),'WDRHBG')

select
avg(value)
from @t2 t2
inner join @t1 t1 on t2.id = t1.name_id and t1.dt < dateadd(d,30,t2.startup_date)
group by t1.name_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Use subquery and `dateadd`

```
 select id,
        startup_date,
        Name,
        (
           select avg(value)
           from table1 t1
           where t1.name_id = t2.id and
                 date between t2.startup_date and dateadd(day, 30, t2.startup_date)
        ) Avg_value
 from table2 t2
```

or `JOIN` with `GROUP BY`

```
 select t2.id,
        t2.startup_date,
        t2.Name,
        avg(value) Avg_value
 from table2 t2
 join table1 t1 on t1.name_id = t2.id and
                   t1.date between t2.startup_date and dateadd(day, 30, t2.startup_date)
 group by t2.id,
          t2.startup_date,
          t2.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select [t2].[Name], AVG([t1].[value]) from [table1] [t1] join [table2] [t2]
on [t1].[name_id] = [t2].[id] and [t1].[date] between [t2].[startup_date] and 
DATEADD(day, 30, [t2].[startup_date])
group by [t2].[Name]
```